# Making the UI buttons function with a keyboard cursor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's what it looks so far

[image]

I've been trying to make a character select, and I'm just kinda near to the final result. The problem is that it doesnt recognizes my cursor which are sprites and gameObjects at the same time.

In this time I just want that my cursor 1 moves through the buttons of the UI elements that brings unity.

This is my script

```
public class CharacterSelect : MonoBehaviour
{

public Button[] WindowsChar = new Button[9];
public Vector3[] Buttondir = new Vector3[9];
public Sprite TextPlayr1, TextPlayr2;
public Canvas orderImage;
public Transform[] posButton, tempos;
public GameObject Cursor1;
public GameObject Cursor2;
int i,v;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    orderImage.sortingOrder = -1; //*This is my intent to make it display the cursors in the canvas*//
    Cursor1.GetComponent<Canvas>().sortingOrder = -2;
    Cursor2.GetComponent<Canvas>().sortingOrder = -2;

    foreach (Button element in WindowsChar) //*For each element of the canvas of the class button, activate it*//
    {
        Debug.Log("Estoy entrando a esta verga"); //it enters to this succesfully//
        WindowsChar[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    Cursor1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = TextPlayr1; //*Initiates the sprites*//
    Cursor2.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = TextPlayr2;
    Cursor1.transform.position = WindowsChar[0].transform.position;//* And then they are put in a default position *//
    Cursor2.transform.position = WindowsChar[1].transform.position;

    Cursor1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    Cursor2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    WindowsChar.GetLength(i);

    foreach (Button element in WindowsChar) //*For each element of type button in windowschar do this with the condition above*//
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && element.FindSelectable(Buttondir[i]) & Cursor1 & i<=3)

 //*If the right keyboard is pressed then moves the cursor*, and also fulfilling the requiste that  ,//
 //finds the selectable button that is next to it, increment the i and moves the cursor, before that saving that in an tempPos//
        {
            Debug.Log("Oh, tambien estoy entrando a esta cosa");
            i = i + 1; //*Incremente el rango a i+1*//

            WindowsChar[i].transform.position = posButton[i].position; //*ahora obtiene la posicion en una variable temporal de i//
            posButton[i].position = tempos[i].position;

            Cursor1.transform.position = tempos[i].position; //*asignandose al cursor y traslandolo al buton necesario**/


        }


    }

  }



}
```

Comment: first you should add `GameObject -> UI -> EventSystem` to your scene. and add event trigger component to it

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, so then I should put the event system in the player 1, and then add a public void option that does the thing in the update isnt it, so that the cursor can translate.

Comment: yes but you can put event system directly in the scene it doesn't have to be a child of player

Comment: Great! I will see if that works then.